# Scala: How can I create a function that has multiple possible return types? (given this edge case inside)

Tags: scala, akka

I am using Akka and scala. And so I am calling either system.actorOf or context.actorOf in my code. However, I am wrapping Akka's library for actor creation so I can add certain functionality. So, the issue arises with how to allow my higher-level abstractions to work in either context. Whether they are called within an environment where system is available (in test code and at the app's kernel) or if they are called within an actor (and only have access to the context variable).

Getting this slapped together and working is easy. Can just make a function that takes both context and system implicitly and returns an ActorRef based on whichever is available. However, to weed out even more duplication I've run into a problem.

There are many other places I'd want to access whichever is in scope (either context or system) automatically. For example, if I want to call system.config or context.system.config, I need to create yet another wrapper function for just that situation.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
appropriate.actorOf(Props[Whatever], name = "breakfast")
```

and the appropriate function returns whichever is available (either actor or system) and then I'd use this function in every place where there is a switch case between the two.

The problem that I run into is that if I return Either[ActorContext, ActorSystem] from a function, I get an error that actorOf is not available on that type. So, it's checking it based on the type, not the fact that it's available on either type no matter which is returned.

Is there a way to do what I am attempting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the subtype `ActorRefFactory` to make this generic as both `ActorContext` and `ActorSystem` inherit from it. You can either return it from your function which figures out which type to return or you can fold the `Either` that you mentioned:

```
  val either:Either[ActorContext, ActorSystem] = ...

  val refProvider =  either.fold[ActorRefFactory](ac => ac, as => as)

  refProvider.actorOf(Props[Whatever], name = "breakfast")
```

***UPDATE***

To answer your question in the comments, first, you're creating an `Either` object so you shouldn't expect to have any method of it's contents available on it. `Either` holds a left or right object and is an object itself with it's own methods. The `fold` over `Either` takes two functions, one with takes a left type and returns a new data type and another function with takes a right type and returns the same data type. By using fold, we can get a value out of the either. If you want to a more in depth look at how this works I highly recommend [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/).

Additionally, you can simplify your code and remove the either all together as it's really unnecessary in your context:

```
  def appropriateContext(implicit context: ActorContext = null, system: ActorSystem = null): ActorRefFactory = {
    if (context != null) context else system
  }
```

Comment: Could anyone explain how this works at the compiler-level? I see how to do this now but I don't understand why it works. Why does folding it make it work? And how does calling refProvider know which one is available to call it on?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this, this is the solution I ended up with:

```
def appropriateContext(implicit context: ActorContext = null, system: ActorSystem = null): ActorRefFactory = {
  val either: Either[ActorContext, ActorSystem] = if (context != null) Left(context) else Right(system)
  val refProvider = either.fold[ActorRefFactory](ac => ac, as => as)
  refProvider
}
```

and then I can call

```
appropriateContext.actorOf(Props[Whatever])
```

This is missing the error handling that I'll add (what to do if both are in scope or neither) but is working.